# How to filter an array?With STL algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, filter, stl

I have a vector which contains expenses.An expense is a struct containg: int id,float amount,string type.I need to filter my array by a given amount.I tried to do something like that,but it doesn't work.Please help me.

```
<Expense> Ctrl::filterbyAmount(vector<Expense>v,float amount){
      vector<Expense>fil;
      remove_copy_if(v.begin(),v.end(),fil.begin(),Filter(amount));
      return fil;                  
 } 
 class Filter{
      Filter(float amount){
          this->amount=amount;
      }
      bool operator()(Expense e){
          return(e.getAmount()==amount);
      }
 private: float amount;
 }
```

and the function getAmount() just return amount of the expense

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: @Pădurean Florina-Alexandra It is not ckear whether you want to get a vector that does not contain the given amount or you want to get a vctor that contains all records with the given amount.

Comment: Sorry,I changed Find2 into Filter.I want to get a vector that contains all records with the given amount

Comment: Then you need `std::copy_if`.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest (and most concise for this example where you don't need a state-preserving functor) is to use a lambda (I assume by now that C++11 is widely available):

```
std::copy_if(v.begin(),v.end(),std::back_inserter(fil),
              [amount](const Expense& e){return e.getAmount() == amount;});
```

---

**NOTE** You need to use `std::back_inserter` (need to `#include <iterator>`) to insert elements into your vector `fil`, since you don't pre-allocate memory for it. `back_inserter` internally uses `push_back`, so you'll be ok. Thanks @juanchopanza for pointing this out.

---

**EDIT**
Your original code doesn't work because you are defining the class `Filter` after the definition of your function, and the latter hence doesn't "see" `Filter`. In any case, a lambda is the best choice here.

Comment: I'd guess the 3rd argument should be something like `std::back_inserter(fil)`.

Comment: @juanchopanza good point, I didn't realize that the vector was not pre-allocated

Comment: Thanks,but it doesn't work.I have an error: remove_copy_if was not declared in this scope

Comment: @PădureanFlorina-Alexandra just make sure you `#include <algorithm>` and `#include <iterator>` And see exactly what you need: either `remove_copy_if` or `copy_if`. One is the negation of the other. Your original code doesn't probably work because you are defining the class `Filter` after the definition of your function, and the latter hence doesn't "see" `Filter`.

Comment: I actually have the class in the header of the file in with i have the function..and it still doesn't work.error: passing 'const Expense' as 'this' argument of 'float Expense::getAmount()' discards qualifiers

Comment: make `getAmount() const` i.e. a const member function, since you are passing a const reference to the lambda.